# React - ES6 - Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I'm getting this error

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Header/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/Gil/Documents/Projects/ecommerce/src/components/Header/index.js: Unexpected token (16:7)

  14 |   }
  15 |
> 16 |   test = () => {
     |        ^
  17 |     console.log('pass!');
  18 |   };
  19 |
```

i think its something with ES6, but i dont know, anyway here's my config

> webpack.config.js

```
loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },...
```

> package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
```

so my problem is, when i try to use `arrow function` i get this error, do i need an extra config or i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: *"when i try to use arrow function i get this error"* The problem is not with the arrow function. It's with the assignment `test = ...;`.

Comment: thanks you @FelixKling, i just flagged it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

and inside `.babelrc`:

```
"plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
```

Comment: You might want to explain why.

Comment: Also, there are presets including not only this proposed language feature but others. For example, the `stage-2` preset currently includes all language features that have reached, well, stage 2 (of 4) along the path towards inclusion in ECMAScript.